# React Native missing script Android

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I added a vector icon package in my React Native app. But After adding vector icon library I am trying to rebuild project using

**npm run android

react-native link**

But it's giving me an error 
npm err missing script android react native

I have tried many solutions of updating package.json file from Github and I have tried to change the path of the environment but still same

Comment: how did you create the project?
also check if `android` script is present in package.json

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong command to make debug build.
Following these steps:

1. install vector icon
2. link it from your project root directory using the command **react-native link your_package_name**
3. Use this command from your project root directory to make build **react-native run-android**

Comment: I have used the command "react-native link react-vector-icons." but still got the error.

Comment: eject the project and then link your package. Run this command ** react-native eject**.